# Removing the raised corners from d3.js axes to create flat axis

Tags: d3.js

D3.js axes typically have "handlebars" on the end of each axis, like this:

[image: axis1]

Those look nice. But.

How can these be removed to make an axis look flat, like this:

[image: axis2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The square ends of the path are sized using either the `.tickSize` method, in which case the *second* argument gives the outer tick size and the first the main tick size, or else using the `.outerTickSize` method. In either case, supply a value of 0 to suppress the ticks.

```
ticks.tickSize(innerTickHeight, 0);
```

or

```
ticks.outerTickSize(0);
```

[Source: page on d3 axes.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes)